# Disable or bypassing name conventions in cakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have following Data:

```
 Database name = ThisDatabase
 Table name    = InfoData
```

cakePHP3 convert the names in

```
 ThisDatabase = this_database
 InfoData    = info_data
```

My problem is that I have no chance to rename the DB or Table names so I have to disable or bypass the name converting in cakePHP3. 
But I have no clue how I can do this.

How can i disable the converting? So I can use the actual names (ThisDatabase and InfoData).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow naming convention for your files and cakephp to work properly, and specify the table name in initialize function inside your `App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable.php`

[Here you can find related documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, CakePHP offers you a way to change the name of the table as you wish.

For the database, in the app config, set the database name :

```
...
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        ...
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'ThisDatabase', // Here you can set the database name
        'encoding' => 'utf8',    
        ..
    ]
],
...
```

Here is some [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration)

For the table name : In your table definition, change the table name

```
class Infodata extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('InfoData');
    }
}
```

Here is is the [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage)